# Asp.net core Autenticação e Autorização de usuários

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Ola, tenho o seguinte problema conceitual e arquitetural de uma aplicação.

-Cenario:

Existe uma aplicação que tem tabela de usuario, permissoes de usuarios e grupos de usuários ja definidas no sistema. Para uma parte dessa aplicação que sera desenvolvida utilizaremos estas permissões para logar, autenticar e  autorizar estes mesmos usuarios c suas respectivas permissoes para operar nessa nova parte da aplicação.

-Duvida:
Toda solução que envolva essa parte de Autenticação e Autorização so vejo documentação e artigos usando o identity do .NET, teria alguma solução alternativa ou eu consigo através dessa minha base ja existente integra-la com o idendity?

*Obs: 
Essa aplicação sera uma SPA em angular consumindo uma API com essas informações de Autenticação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível alterar as tabelas usadas pelo Identity, entretanto, ainda seria necessário que a sua estrutura de tabelas fosse compatível com o mesmo. Para qualquer outra alternativa "pronta" o problema seria o mesmo.

Para criar a sua própria alternativa seria necessário ter conhecimento de todos os seus requisitos (inclusive a estrutura das tabelas existentes) e imagino que não conseguiria uma resposta no SO.

Se a sua questão for "como implementar o identity usando a uma estrutura específica de dados", [o código do .net é open source e vc está livre para modificá-lo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src).

Agora, se a sua questão for "como ter autenticação e autorização", não é necessário fazer uso do identity. Vc poderia usar JWT, por exemplo.

Seguindo as instruções [deste post](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) você pode proteger os seus endpoints da mesma forma, com o `AuthorizeAttribute` e usar os métodos `AddAuthentication`, `AddJwtBearer`, `UseAuthentication` e `UseAuthorization` para configurar a autenticação.

Em `Startup.Configure`

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Em `Startup.ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
  x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
  (Suas configurações...)
});

services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

`IUserService`

```
public interface IUserService
{
  User Authenticate(string username, string password);
  IEnumerable<User> GetAll();
}
```

`UserService`: Implemente conforme as suas necessidades.

Para implementar **autorização** pode se tornar um pouco mais complexo, dependendo das suas tabelas existentes. Caso seja possível mapear os dados existentes para *roles*, bastaria adicionar a claim `ClaimTypes.Role` ao token do usuário e proteger os métodos com `[Authorize(Roles = Role.Admin)]`, conforme demostrado [neste outro exemplo](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/16/aspnet-core-3-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api).

Comment: muito obrigado, irei utilizar JWT para implementar as autorizações com a base ja existente.